# C# video flickering

Tags: c#, windows-xp, transparency, vlc, flicker

I am having an issue in my code, which shows a video using the VLC interface.  I'm also showing an overlay on top of that video (in full screen) using the "Form Transparency" capability.

This is fine on my Windows 7 PC, but it is getting flickering in XP machine.

If you can help me solve this, I would appreciate your help.  I need to show a UDP:// stream so I'm having to use VLC, yet at the same time I need to show my program's information on top of the video...